# Routing in Silex/Symfony. Providing a default route

Tags: symfony, routes, silex

I'm attempting to do something using Silex (which uses the Symfony routing component - so the answer may be applicable to Symfony as well)

I am adding Silex to a legacy application to provide routing but I need to respect the existing applications default implementation for loading files (which is simply to load the file from the file system form the URL specified).

*edit: for clarification:
Existing file is loaded from the file system, as an include within an parent template, after a series of bootstrapping calls have been made.*

What I'm finding is that in the absence of a defined route to match the legacy pages, Silex is throwing an exception.

I really need a way to provide a default (fallback) mechanism for handling those legacy pages - but my pattern has to match the entire url (not just one fragment).

Is this possible?

```
// Include Silex for routing    
require_once(CLASS_PATH . 'Silex/silex.phar');

// Init Silex
$app = new Silex\Application();

    // route for new code
    // matches for new restful interface (like /category/add/mynewcategory)

    $app->match('/category/{action}/{name}/', function($action, $name){
        //do RESTFUL things
    });

    // route for legacy code (If I leave this out then Silex
    // throws an exception beacuse it hasn't matched any routes

    $app->match('{match_the_entire_url_including_slashes}', function($match_the_entire_url_including_slashes){
        //do legacy stuff
    });

    $app->run();
```

This must be a common use case. I'm trying to provide a way to have a RESTFUL interface alongside legacy code (load   /myfolder/mysubfolder/my_php_script.php)

Comment: I have a question regarding your question , should not the url rewriting on apache handle already existing files without mapping the url to your index.php file ? sounds strange ...

Comment: @camus No, because I needed to route every request in my application through the front controller in order to bootstrap the application (security, database connection etc.). edit: I've added a clarification to the question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the answer within the symfony cookbook...

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

```
$app->match('{url}', function($url){
    //do legacy stuff
})->assert('url', '.+');
```

Comment: in which file would you put the code above? And does it co-exist with routes.yaml?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the error handling, with something like that :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return new Response('The requested page could not be found. '.$app['request']->getRequestUri(), 404);
    }
    $code = ($e instanceof HttpException) ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;
    return new Response('We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.', $code);
});
```

Comment: Hi Charles, the problem wasn't that the error wasn't being handled - but rather that it was being thrown in the first place. I found a solution to my problem. Thanks for your input.